# Associations/Relations 0:1 sequelize between tables

Tags: sequelize.js, associations, relation

I would like to create a relation 0:1 between 1 table and 3 different tables but I didn't see any relation like that in sequelize (only 1:1 , 1:n , n:m). Is it possible with sequelize?

In my database, I would like to have:

- My main_table has 3 relations 0:1 with each of the following tables: table_p , table_d and table_v. This will be 1 key (value_id) in my main_table. Value_id is the primary_key of 1 of the 3 tables.
- My main_table has 1 relation 1:1 with 1 table: table_indication. The table_indication (primary key table_indication_id) explain witch table I should get the information (if table_indication_id=1 it's a value of the table_p, if table_indication_id=2 it's a value of the table_d, if table_indication_id=3 it's a value of the table_v).

  The design of my tables:
- Main_table: id, value_id (the primary_key of the 'table_p', 'table_d' or 'table_v'), table_indication_id (the primary_key of the table table_indication)
- table_indication: id, name ('table_p', 'table_d' or 'table_v')
- table_p: id, name
- table_d: id, name
- table_v: id, name

Answer (score 0):

1 attribute in my main_table can be the value of the primary key of 3 different table.
How to modelize that in sequelize ?

- Should I have 1 attribute in my main_table for my 3 primary key ?
- or should I have 3 attributes in my main_table (1 attribute for each primary key of my 3 table) ?